# How to configure the Test Controller Configuration Tool version for 2013?

Tags: testing, configuration, permissions, controller, administrator

I'm working with Automated Builds becuse I need to do automatic Build, Deploy and Test in every Check in. So searching how to do it, if found things bout Build Definition (done), Lab Enviroments (not done) and Test Controller Configuration (not done yet).
Right now I'm stuck in the Configure Test Controller dialogbox because I have the next error:

Configuration failed

User Josue Rocha is not authorized to grant permissions to test controller service. To fix this error, run this tool woth an account that has "Project Collection Administrator" rights and try again.

My point is, I am already member of the Project Collection Test Service Accounts and based on this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546460.aspx#SettingUpTestControllersSecurity

I tought it could work but it didn't.

Can any body help me please!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The user launching the config tool needs to have the "Manage Test Controllers" permission to be able to configure a test controller against the TFS project collection. During the configuration process the service account you are configuring your controller with is added to the "Test Service accounts" group.